# How do I change my work place in the calendar?

Tags: calendar

When I put my work times into the calendar, I would like to just click on the word "work" and have it put in a nice piccie of my workplace. Unfortunately the calendar has decided I work in a suburb of the same name on a different continent. I can't figure out how to edit this.

This is on the gmail calendar